# Issue with PowerShell script to remotely reboot session

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

Problem with the script is that always reboots my own PC and not the IP or session mentioned. Line by line it should work but I am not seeing the issue.

Any suggestions are appreciated:

```
#Security Policy
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

#Adding the range of IP address for Trading network
Set-Item -Path WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -value '10.22.*'

#IP address of the target PC, hostnames doesn't seems to be working
$targetpc = Read-Host "Please enter the IP Address of the target PC"

New-PSSession $targetpc -Credential(Get-Credential)

$sessionid = Read-Host "Please enter the session ID"

Enter-PSSession -Id $sessionid

Write-Host Test

[string]$forcereboot = Read-Host "Would you like to force reboot the PC ? [y][n]"

if ($forcereboot -eq "y") {
    #Restart-Computer -Force
    Stop-Process -Name "Notepad"
}

else { Exit-PSSession }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here the `Restart-Computer` executes in the local machine itself.

`Enter-PSSession` is for interactive remoting and cannot be used in a script.
And to reboot a remote computer, you don't require a session to be created. You can Use `-ComputerName` parameter of `Restart-Computer` cmdlet to reboot a remote host.

```
#Example
Restart-Computer -ComputerName $Computer
```

And if you still want to use WSMAN for this , you can use the session with `Invoke-Command`

```
 Invoke-Command -Session $SessionObject { Restart-Computer -Force }
```